# jquery Selectors

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a simple code using jQuery, in which I need to call a function for a series of selectors and eliminate some functions being called for a particular selector, for example

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function() {
 function1();
 function2();
 function3();
 // rest of my code 
});
```

I don't wanna call some **functions** for a particular selector and for a particular reason, say I want to call all the functions when I perform click event on selectors like **id1** and **id2** and want to eliminate  **function2()** being called when I perform a click event on **id3**

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `event target` within your click event handler.

For instance:

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function(event) {
  function1();

  if(event.target.id !== 'id2')
     function2();

  function3();
  // rest of my code 
});
```

Comment: I like the event target, I sometimes overlook that.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to execute the `function2()` for the `id2` you could do

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function() {
  function1();
  if (this.id != 'id2')
    function2();
  function3();
  // rest of my code 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

separate them:

```
$('#id1, #id2').click(function() { 
 function1(); 
 function2(); 
 function3(); 
 // rest of my code  
}); 
$('#id3').click(function() { 
 function1();  
 function3(); 
 // rest of my code  
});
```

OR detect which one and put in a conditional:

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function() { 
 function1(); 
 if ($(this).attr('id')!=id3)
 {
   function2(); 
 };
 function3(); 
 // rest of my code  
});
```