# multiple input field jquery.autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, textfield

i want to make autocomplete for many text input field...
but with this autocomplete

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {
      $("#perkiraan").autocomplete("proses_akun.php", { width:350, max:28, scroll:false });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo" style="width: 250px;">
<div>
<p>Nama Akun : <input type="text" id="perkiraan"  name="perkiraan" size="65"></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="pilihan">
</div>

<div class="demo" style="width: 250px;"><div>
<p>Nama Akun : <input type="text" id="perkiraan"  name="perkiraan" size="65"></p>
</div>
</div>  

<div id="pilihan">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i know it because only one same name permit for this jquery...
but i want to add more input text (second, third, etc) below the first that using javascript too without copy paste the scriot and change its name...
help please,,,,

Comment: means you want to trigger same event ie `autocomplete`  for other textbox

Comment: it may help you link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102826/jquery-selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/nckYT/

Please note DOM should never have the same `id` attributes for elements which is the case in the sample above. i.e. `id="perkiraan"` **solution** use `class` attribute instead.

I think the official doc says that if there are multiple same `id` then it takes the last `id`-ied element as the identified element.

**further for mutiple element** you can use class element for autocomplete like this `$( ".perkiraan" ).autocomplete({` that will attach autocomplete with all the elements with class `perkiraan`. **or** you can chain the different `id`s like `$( "#perkiraan, #foo" ).autocomplete({` but addaing class will do the trick

Hope this helps, lemme know if I missed anything, `:)`

**cose**

```
<body><div class="demo" style="width: 250px;">
    <div><p>Nama Akun : <input type="text" class="perkiraan"  name="perkiraan" size="65"></p></div></div><div id="pilihan"></div>
    <div class="demo" style="width: 250px;">
<div><p>Nama Akun : <input type="text" class="perkiraan"  name="perkiraan" size="65"></p></div></div>  <div id="pilihan"></div></body>
```

**Image 1 input 1** 
[image]

**Image 2 input 2** 
[image]

Comment: but it same, still only 1 textfield that can use autocomplete,the second,etc cannot use it...

Comment: @Myan nopes see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/nckYT/ type 1 on both the text boxes and you will see autocomplete working for both, I have attached images as well to show you that, also if I may recommend please read HTML docs and Jquery docs, but above working demo should help `:)`

Comment: but it same, still only 1 textfield that can use autocomplete,the second,etc cannot use it...
`<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {$(".id_perkiraan").autocomplete("j query/js/cari.php",{width:350, max:28, scroll:false });});
        </script>`
`<div class="demo" >
     <div><p><input type="text" name="id_perkiraan[]" class="id_perkiraan" size=75 autocomplete="off">
     </p></div>
     </div>
       <div class="pilihan"></div>`

Comment: It is problem with your HTML then, also I can only see one text box in your code `<input type="text" name="id_perkiraan[]" class="id_perkiraan" size=75 autocomplete="off">` Also Json has nothing to do with your question, its just the data feed, check your php file as well. Can you please recreate your issue in jsfiddle and I might help you out, p.s. hope your path is correct `"j query/js/cari.php"`

Comment: here is my php:
`$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
 $query = mysql_query("select * from perkiraan where id_perkiraan LIKE '%$q%'");
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
 {$id = $r['id_perkiraan'];
 $nama = $r['nama'];
 echo "$id [$nama] \n";
 }`
and javascript like this `
$().ready(function(){$( ".id_perkiraan" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( req, resp ) {$( "j query/js/cari.php", {
            delay: 1}, function(data) {resp( data );
        }, "JSON" );}});});`
and still not work...

Comment: @Myan I can have a look but I don't know what you are trying to do if you want to add `autocmplete` in multiple input box above demo will help, if you have demo issue you need to read yur code and figure it out anyhoo where is the php? code

Comment: @Myan No worries man, I think you need to see what wrong in your syntax to start with don't panic though, anyhoo, I am fixing hard to understand you other question, As far as I can see your `fetching data` part is not returning any data hence the failure of `autocomplete` i.e. identify the problem area, **further** in terms of attaching multiple fields with autocomplete demo above will help `:)` have a good one,

Comment: i have found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271294/multi-textfield-with-autocomplete-but-why-only-first/11271413#11271413

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just change `$("#perkiraan").autocomplete` to `$(".classname").autocomplete`
and you are done

**Note** : class name should be same in all text fields