# multi textfield with autocomplete but why only first

Tags: php, javascript, autocomplete

with autocomplete javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="j query/js/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="j query/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>{/literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $(".id_perkiraan").autocomplete("j query/js/cari.php",{width:350, max:28, scroll:false });
    });
</script>
```

html :

```
<tr>
    <td width="75">
        <div class="demo">
            <div>
                <p><input type="text" name="id_perkiraan[]" class="id_perkiraan" size=75 autocomplete="off"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pilihan"></div> 
    </td>
    <td><input type ='text' name='keterangan[]' size="20"></td>
    <td><input type ='text' name='debet[]' size="20" ></td>
    <td><input type ='text' name='kredit[]' size="20" ></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td width="75">
        <div class="demo">
            <div>
                <p><input type="text" name="id_perkiraan[]" class="id_perkiraan" size=75 autocomplete="off"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pilihan"></div> 
    </td>
    <td><input type ='text' name='keterangan[]' size="20"></td>
    <td><input type ='text' name='debet[]' size="20" ></td>
    <td><input type ='text' name='kredit[]' size="20" ></td>
</tr>
```

and the cari.php :

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("siakud");

$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
    $query = mysql_query("select * from perkiraan where id_perkiraan LIKE '%$q%'");
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {  
        $id = $r['id_perkiraan'];
        $nama = $r['nama'];
        echo "$id [$nama] \n";
    }
?>
```

but somehow only one 'id_perkiraan' text field that have autocomplete work...
how for second, third adn etc 'id_perkiraan'???

Comment: I don't see why people just like to add a `[]` in the `name`... It will make it invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

You use only "id.perkiraan" ,other textfields are not used in jquery

which textfield want autocomplete ,use keyup,other suitable functions

```
$(".id_perkiraan").autocomplete(...)
$("other").autocomplete(...)
```

I have tried autocomplete plugin used.. i have changed "box" value, more than one textfields access completed. so you have try in your code..

```
function check(na)
{
    var tmp=document.getElementById(na).value;
    box='#'+na; 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'fetch.php',
    data: "val="+tmp,
    success: function(data) 
    {   
        if(data!="")
        {
            //$('#err_register').html(data);
            var data1=data.split(','); // alert(data1.length);
            //$('#pname').focus().autocomplete(data1);
            $(box).focus().autocomplete(data1); 
        }

    } 
    });
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, my browser say 'na' is null value....
i have try change na, with id_perkiraan (id of my text field)

Comment: "na" is textfeild id. call this function check(this.id) any text field

Comment: yes i'm trying it, but how to call it...
i try `<input type="text" id="id_perkiraan" onBlur="check(this.id);" />` didn't show result....
how ??

Comment: i found the answer , i change the code like that 
`function check(na)
{var tmp=document.getElementById(na).value;
    box='#'+na; 
    $().ready(function() {$(box).autocomplete("j query/js/cari.php",{width:350, max:28, scroll:false });});}`

and for input text :
`<input type="text" id="idperkiraan" onKeyPress="checky(this.id);" onClick="checky(this.id);">`
thx alot